# DataNavigator and INavigatorLayout

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I think my question is for advanced flex developers or experts.
My task is relatively simple: I need to build some kind of horizontal "gallery" component, and IMGO the new [DataNavigator](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/DataNavigator.html)  from new Apache 4.10 SDK suits best for this task. 
In other words I need the same as DataNavigator with a specific INavigatorLayout - the same as [CarouselLayout](http://www.tink.ws/blog/carousellayout/) , but much simpler - without any perspective but with smooth transition between items. May be such layouts already exists?

Thanks for advance.
Andrew.

Comment: IMGO = I Must Get Oppenent. Anyway, I've found solution, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the solution that satisfied me, it works for me, but the main idea:

```
package 
{
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import spark.layouts.HorizontalLayout;
import spark.layouts.supportClasses.INavigatorLayout;
import mx.core.IVisualElement;

/**
 * @author Andrew
 */
public class LobbyNavigatorLayout3 extends HorizontalLayout implements INavigatorLayout
{
    public function LobbyNavigatorLayout3()
    {
    }


    private var _selectedElement:IVisualElement;
    public function get selectedElement() : IVisualElement
    {
        return  _selectedElement;
    }

    public function get selectedIndex() : int
    {
        return target.getElementIndex(_selectedElement);
    }

    public var ttt:Number = 0;

    public function set selectedIndex(value : int) : void
    {
        if (!target) return;
        var firstEl:IVisualElement = target.getElementAt(0);
        if (!firstEl) return;

        var shift:Number = (600 + gap) * value;

        TweenLite.to(this, 1, {ttt:shift, onUpdate:function ():void { 


            updateDisplayList(target.width, target.height);
            }} );

        _selectedElement = target.getElementAt(value);

    }


    override public function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth : Number, unscaledHeight : Number) : void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        for (var i : int = 0; i < target.numElements; i++) 
        {
            var el:IVisualElement = target.getElementAt(i);
            el.setLayoutBoundsPosition(el.x - ttt, 0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

need to say that this is for useVirtualLayout = false; Some extra work needed to fix this, but it suits for me for now, and if you are feel like you are able to do this - you are welcome!